# How can I connect to ethereum with only a web browser to monitor a contract

Tags: web3js, light-clients, ethereumjs

AFAICT it requires a node such as geth to connect to ethereum to get or change  contract state.

I only need to get state, not change state, but I want to do it only from a web browser.  I don't want to have to install an ethereum node on every device that wishes to view the state.  I also want to view and present the state in a particular way, so I don't want to use one of the blockchain browsing websites (they discourage applications using their websites anyways).

Do the ethereumjs libraries provide this capability?  If not, are there plans to build this capability?

Answer (score 4):

You need to a node to be running somewhere if you want to monitor a contract. However, there's no need for this node to be running on every device that's viewing it: You can run this on your own server, or you can pay someone to provide this as a service. (Or if you're lucky maybe you can find someone who's doing it for free - I don't know of anyone, YMMV...)

If you're running a node on a server, there are two ways you can get the information to clients that want to see what's happening with your contract:

1. Configure your Ethereum node to listen to requests from any address on the internet, rather than just being limited to localhost. This is just a configuration setting - normally people use localhost for security reasons but there's no technical limitation on it. (You probably don't want to store any money on the node you set up to do this...) Then have the devices connect to your node's RPC interface using the server's address, rather than localhost.
2. Leave your Ethereum node on localhost and make a separate web server process that listens to your Ethereum node on localhost, and listens to users's devices on the public internet, and passes along the information information it gets from Ethereum to the users' devices. I've done this before using express.js to run a web server process and socket.io to send out updates to clients in real time.

Comment: so the ethereumjs code base, which purports to separate out the p2p networking protocol and other components (according to their github page), will be unable to just get basic block info in a browser via that protocol?  I'm familiar with nodejs but not that familiar with browser limitations.

Comment: Infrua provides a running remote node if you don't want (or can't) run your own.